# How to enforce the text filled in flowchart follow single line space?

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

My document is in a `doublespace` environment using `elsarticle` template, that is the whole document is two double line space .

I searched the solutions, like `setspace` package. I used it as follows:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{singlespace}    
 my flowchart    
\end{singlespace}
```

The result is that the flowchart and following content are all single line space. In order to keep the content following the flowchart double line space, I do it as follows:

```
\usepackage{setspace}    
\begin{singlespace}    
 my flowchart    
\end{singlespace}    

\begin{doublespace}    
 following content    
\end{doublespace}
```

But it did not work. The results is the same as previous one.

Can anyone help me out? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post a small example so the we can see what you mean exactly?

Comment: One can nest a `singlespace` environment inside a `doublespace` environment without problems.

Comment: @ percusse I want to post a small example but many files consisit the elsarticle template. So it must upload the relative documents.

Comment: @Andrew Swann Can you leave a simple example? I am beginner in compiling tex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that (a) you use `elsarticle` class and (b) that you enclosed the body of the text in a `doublespace` environment.  I guess that you do not use `\doublespacing` in your preamble as the ruins layouts of titles.  Anyway, you can get a single space region inside the double spaced body by simply using the `singlespacing` environment.  In the code below the `lipsum` package and the `\lipsum` commands just produce some text for demonstration purposes:

[image: Sample page]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\journal{Nuclear Physics B}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{doublespace}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{singlespace}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{singlespace}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Essentially the same output (slightly less widely doublespaced) is produced from:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\journal{Nuclear Physics B}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{singlespace}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{singlespace}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Internally `elsarticle` does not use `setspace` but defines a `baselinestretch` parameter `\@blstr` to be `1.5` in the review style.

Comment: Actually, I used the \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}, which automatically generates double linespace content without \begin{doublespace} and \end{doublespace}. Then I tried to single line space of the content in flowchart using my mentioned way. But it didn't work out. Thanks for your reply!